# Calculate Cosine Similarity Using java Program

Tags: java, tf-idf, trigonometry

I have a problem to calculate a similarity measurement to develop a search engine for my final project.

I have to use **tf idf + cosine** similarity in java and I don't have any idea how to calculate it.

For your information, I have my own database which has 811 document

Answer (score 1):

To compute the cosine similarity of vector u and v, normalize u and v and then get dot product of u and v. It implies the vectors have the same size and are numerical vectors (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) Coding such operations is trivial, and some people did it for you, like here http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

In a search engine, cosine similarity can be a measure of how much object A matches B. Your query is an object A, compute cosine similarity for all objects B in your database/store/whatever, the B objects sort by decreasing similarity.

If your objects are numeric vectors, easy enough. If not, then you have to devise a way to turn your objects into numeric vectors. For instance, for text data, the vector can contains the number of times some keywords occurs in the text, it's called "bag of words model" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) Such a model totally ignore how words relate to each other. A smarter way, that takes in account simple relationship between words, can be computing for a given text the probability that a given word follow an other, it's a Markovian representation. The vector is then a vector of probabilities that word x follows y.